# Use website on local host

Tags: php

It is hard to explain but maybe someone will understand.

I have created four pages on a website named: homepage.php, page1.php, page2.php and page3.php. I have downloaded and installed WAMP developer. It creates a folder named webroot on desktop. I move my files in the webroot folder. Now when I open local host I can see those four files. And I can open them by clicking on them. Works fine.

That's ok but what I want is when I open the local host I want to see homepage.php. Also I want page1 file in the  directory http://homepage.php/page1 (like a original website). But now, all pages lie in the same directory for example localhost/homepage.php, localhost/page1.php and so on.

I know it's complicated to understand. I can't find any solution. Please help.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but index.php in the root folder will be executed when you navigate to root of `localhost`

Comment: i changes the homepage.php to index.php and now i can see home page and page1.php file in directory localhost/page1.php, but is there anything for further links i mean supose i want to go localhost/page1.php/page4.php like this site have four links stackoverflow.com/questions/38643354/use-website-on-local-host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost is the root of your site. Therefore you use http://localhost.
This will open the index.html or index.php contained in the root directory. If you wish to open a certain file you will have to locate it like so:
`http://localhost/directory-name/file-name.php`

However you can't have `file-name.php/other-file.php`

The URL is made up of the **root**, the **directory path** and the **file name**

`localhost/folder-one/folder-two/file-one.php`

```
 ↑          ↑           ↑          ↑
 |                |                |
root        directory path        file
```

Comment: thanks Ivan. sometimes big problems have very small solution.

Comment: i changes the homepage.php to index.php and now i can see the page1.php file in directory localhost/page1.php, but is there anything for further links i mean supose i want to go  localhost/page1.php/page4.php like this  site have four links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643354/use-website-on-local-host

Comment: you can't really do that, however you could create a folder named page1 and add page4.php inside it. This way you will be able to navigate to page4.php with `localhost/page1/page4.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of `homepage.php` to `index.php`

For your other pages, create folders like "/page1/" and inside that folder put `page1.php` and rename it to index.php as well.

Your structure might look as follows:

```
index.php          (previously homepage.php)
/page1/index.php   (previously page1.php)
/page2/index.php   (previously page2.php)
/page3/index.php   (previously page3.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is to have `page1.php` exist at your root directory, but `your-url.com/page1/` to open `page1.php`, you're going to need to rely on `.htaccess`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^page(.*)/?$  /page$1.php [NC]
```